# MongoDB - aggregating with nested objects, and changeable keys

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document which describes counts of different things observed by a camera within a 15 minute period. It looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1a709a83552d002516ac19"),
    "start" : ISODate("2018-06-08T11:45:00.000Z"),
    "end" : ISODate("2018-06-08T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "recording" : ObjectId("5b1a654683552d002516ac16"),
    "data" : {
        "counts" : {
            "5b434d05da1f0e00252566be" : 12,
            "5b434d05da1f0e00252566cc" : 4,
            "5b434d05da1f0e00252566ca" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

The keys inside the `data.counts` object **change** with each document and refer to additional data that is fetched at a later date. There are unlimited number of keys inside data.counts (but usually about 20)

I am trying to aggregate all these 15 minute documents up to daily aggregated documents.

I have this query at the moment to do that:

```
db.getCollection("segments").aggregate([
    {$match:{
       "recording": ObjectId("5bf7f68ad8293a00261dd83f")
    }}, 
    {$project:{
        "start": 1,
        "recording": 1,
        "data": 1
    }},
    {$group:{
        _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$start" } },
        "segments": { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }},
    {$sort: {_id: -1}},
]);
```

This does the grouping and returns all the `segments` in an array.

I want to also aggregate the information inside `data.counts`, so that I get the sum of values for all keys that are the same within the daily group.

This would save me from having another service loop through each 15 minute segment summing values with the same keys. E.g. the query would return something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "2019-02-27",
    "counts" : {
        "5b434d05da1f0e00252566be" : 351,
        "5b434d05da1f0e00252566cc" : 194,
        "5b434d05da1f0e00252566ca" : 111
        ... any other keys that were found within a day
    }
}
```

How might I amend the query I already have, or use a different query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) pipeline stage to create two sub-pipelines; one for `segments` and another for `counts`. These sub-pipelines can be joined by using [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) to stitch them together and [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to merge each 2-element array produced from zip. Note this will only work correctly if the sub-pipelines output sorted arrays of the same size, which is why we group and sort by `start_date` in each sub-pipeline.

Here's the query:

```
db.getCollection("segments").aggregate([{
    $match: {
        recording: ObjectId("5b1a654683552d002516ac16")
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        start: 1,
        recording: 1,
        data: 1,
        start_date: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$start" }}
    }
}, {
    $facet: {
        segments_pipeline: [{
            $group: {
                _id: "$start_date",
                segments: {
                    $push: {
                        start: "$start",
                        recording: "$recording",
                        data: "$data"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $sort: {
                _id: -1
            }
        }],
        counts_pipeline: [{
            $project: {
                start_date: "$start_date",
                count: { $objectToArray: "$data.counts" }
            }
        }, {
            $unwind: "$count"
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    start_date: "$start_date",
                    count_id: "$count.k"
                },
                count_sum: { $sum: "$count.v" }
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id.start_date",
                counts: {
                    $push: {
                        $arrayToObject: [[{
                            k: "$_id.count_id",
                            v: "$count_sum"
                        }]]
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $project: {
                counts: { $mergeObjects: "$counts" }
            }
        }, {
            $sort: {
                _id: -1
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        result: {
            $map: {
                input: { $zip: { inputs: ["$segments_pipeline", "$counts_pipeline"] }},
                in: { $mergeObjects: "$$this" }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$result"
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$result"
    }
}])
```

Try it out here: [Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FkpcjZkbZQ7).